# Centralizing Kendo Validator Custom Rules

Tags: javascript, validation, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-validator

I plan to have a few custom rules for my kendo validator, that I want to share across all my validators.  In my code on a validator, I have:

```
rules: {
    bothorblank: function (input) {
        ...
    },
    mutualexclusive: function(input) {

    }
}
```

Since I'm using the open source version, is there an easy way to centralize the rules across all validators?  Is there a static property I set with the rules?  Or is the best way to define a generic method that returns an object, and call that during initialization time?

Comment: generic method  is your solution , there is no static property .

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same scenario I made some tweaks to make the custom rules as global which works across pages/sites. Here is the blog that explains and here you can find the demo.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/chandarmk/vrrq5wyu/

Blog - http://thirum.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/kendo-custom-global-validator/

Here is some code sample

```
 kendo.ui.validator.rules.isValidDate = function (input, params) {

    //ignore all other input that doesnt have this attribute
    //case insensitive
    if (!(input.is('[data-isValidDate]') || input.is('[data-isvaliddate]'))) return true;

    var retVal = false;

    var kendoDatePicker = input.data("kendoDatePicker");
    if (kendoDatePicker) {
        var d = kendo.parseDate(kendoDatePicker.value(), ["yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt", "yyyy/MM/dd", "MM/dd/yyyy", "MMM dd, yyyy"]);
        retVal = d instanceof Date;
        if (retVal) input.closest('.k-datepicker').removeClass("red-box");
        else input.closest('.k-datepicker').addClass("red-box");
    }

    return retVal;
}
```